# Merge [skydrive] into [onedrive]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Since Microsoft rebranded, there are 170ish questions with [skydrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skydrive) that need tagged with [onedrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedrive).

Can we get a synonym to "rename" [skydrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skydrive)?

Comment: Is this one of those times where the tag is sufficiently obscure that there's no one with [the requisite 5 score to propose a synonym](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag)?

Comment: im guessing so or that people weren't aware they could do that. i certainly don't have enough.

Comment: Is there someone with the requisite 5 score who would be happy to propose the synonym, then? :)

Comment: I'm trying ;) First answer in [tag:onedrive] tag http://stackoverflow.com/a/27904393/993547