# More guidance on the onedrive tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, outsourcing

We all know that Microsoft points to SO as community support for the OneDrive SDK's ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/onedrive), click 'Community' in the top bar).

The link now points to the [onedrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedrive) tag wiki, which is an excellent point to include some extra guidance for people coming here fresh.

Do you think it is useful to edit the wiki, and so, what should go there?

Some ideas:

- guidance on asking and finding duplicates;
- some links to meta faq's.

Also take note of [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269604/merge-skydrive-into-onedrive) a while ago on meta concerning the merging of the [onedrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedrive) and [skydrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skydrive) tags.

Comment: Latest example on 'misuse' of the tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888665/an-unexpected-processing-error-occurred-please-contact-microsoft. Please take it easy on OP, I think MS is to blame here.

Comment: yea we need someone to reach out to microsoft. ive added the outsourcing tag.

Comment: The tag was edited by Jeanine of the OneDrive team at Microsoft.  Isn't that good enough?  They are certainly on top of it, the top 5 posters in the tag are all team members.

Comment: @HansPassant well, they might come to meta some time to approve the tag synonym... I believe their intentions are good, but they might need a little help on how SE rolls.

Comment: @HansPassant I left a comment under one of Ryan's answers to make him aware of this post.

Comment: What about the tag [onedrive-api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedrive-api)?

Comment: @rene not that important since Microsoft links the onedrive tag wiki from their own site. The other tag can be useful too, but is less important.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is my take on the wiki for the tag [onedrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedrive)

**OneDrive** (formerly known as SkyDrive, Windows Live SkyDrive, and Windows Live Folders) is a file hosting service that allows users to upload and sync files to a cloud storage and then access them from a web browser or their local device.

You can use this tag on questions that are about **programming** with the OneDrive API's. If you're about to ask your first question here please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) because that gives you a better chance of getting your question answered.

Also note that you can [browse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedrive?sort=newest) the current questions for [onedrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedrive). 
Use [the search capabilites](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to search for questions with an accepted answer for example about [REST](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bonedrive%5D+rest++isaccepted%3Ayes).

---

**General support** Do note that for general support issues, like questions about your account, contracts, billing, the OneDrive website, use of any of the OneDrive apps among other non-programming related things, you still need to contact Microsoft either directly or via your local representative.

---

Under this tag questions can be asked about:

- [Scopes and permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631845.aspx)
- [Representational State Transfer (REST) API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631844.aspx)
- [JavaScript API (Windows Store app and web)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243643.aspx)
- [Managed API (Windows Store app and Windows Phone)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh533665.aspx)
- [iOS interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847068.aspx)
- [Packages for  Android apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846809.aspx)
- [OneDrive Pickers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn782252.aspx)

OneDrive is part of the Windows Live range of online services and allows users to keep the files private, share them with contacts, or make the files public. Publicly shared files do not require a Microsoft account to access.

In addition to personal cloud storage, Microsoft offers managed business storage as OneDrive for Business.

**External links:**

- OneDrive Dev Center: http://dev.onedrive.com
- OneDrive Product: http://onedrive.com/about
- OneDrive UserVoice Forum: http://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive
- Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_OneDrive

**These SE communities might be of help if you have user related questions:**

- [Super User](https://superuser.com/tags/onedrive/info) for questions about using the drive synchronization feature
- [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/onedrive/info) for questions about using the web interface
- [Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/tags/onedrive/info) for questions about using the Windows Phone app
- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/onedrive/info) for questions about using the Android app

Comment: I like this wiki article. It would also be useful to add links to our [user voice page](http://onedrive.uservoice.com).

Comment: For the types of issues that aren't SO appropriate, users and developers can use the "Submit Feedback" link on the OneDrive website (it's under the gear icon in the top bar of the site). We're working on getting a developer version of this form available from dev.onedrive.com, but it's taking longer that I'd like.

Comment: @RGregg: Thanks for commenting. Can you post the link please?

Comment: @rene: I updated the tag wiki. Thanks for your massive input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on the wiki excerpt for the tag [onedrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedrive)

Use this tag if you have a programming question about OneDrive (formerly known as  SkyDrive). OneDrive is a file hosting service, supported with SDK's and a REST API for developers, that allows users to upload and sync files to a cloud storage and then access them from a Web browser or their local device. For non-programming questions contact your local Microsoft customer support representative.