# Can I create a tag that I know will be used very soon?

Tags: discussion, tags

> Before you jump at my throat, I've read "[preemptively create a tag with no questions asked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285355/can-should-we-preemptively-create-a-tag-with-no-questions-asked)" already, but can't really relate to that since it's very MS specific now.

### Some context

At Podio we're about to redirect our **API developer community** on SO for questions strictly related to Podio's API usage and troubleshooting.

We will still maintain **all our general purpose forums** like discussions and feature requests on https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/community/topics. On top of that, we still have a support team replying to tickets and supporting customers. I'm saying all of this because I want to emphasise that we only want to move our developer community here on SO, not "outsource" our support.

I would like people to post their questions under the [podio-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/podio-api) tag, which doesn't exist at the time being (only [podio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/podio) is there). Some (most?) of our community developers will not have enough rep to create a new tag (I barely have it myself) and it will be harder for us to keep track of the new questions without a nifty handle to search for.

### The dilemma

- Can I create a question myself to create the tag and then remove it (SO's Roomba hopefully won't scoop it up because it will be populated most likely the same day or the day after)?
- Or should I post the last question that arrived in the forum and reply to it?
- Or none of it and just hope someone will create the tag?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124712/how-to-create-a-new-tag-without-asking-question

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I read that already and believe we fit that description perfectly (that's the reason why I provided some context)

Comment: Yep, just adding a link for context. There's also the last sentence: *If you have questions about these guidelines or need help creating and managing your tags, contact us and we'll give you a hand.* :)

Comment: Do you think that people currently active in `podio` would be unable or unwilling to act on questions you'd now tag `podio-api`? Or would they just end up tagged with both and answered by the same people?

Comment: Following @rene's answer I will stick to `podio`, as questions will probably be marked as both `podio` and `podio-api` if I introduce that tag. No need to add noise to SO

Comment: @domokun Keep in mind, Stack Overflow is specifically for *development* questions, which implies the [tag:podio] tag will exclusively relate to your API at this point.  There are many other Stack Exchange sites, though, several of which could be used for non-developer questions. [Take a look](http://stackexchange.com/sites) and check to see if there are existing Podio tags on any of them--I bet there are.  How about [Project Management](http://pm.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Zenexer `Or is Meta exempt from this guideline?` yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't create a tag out of the blue as is explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124714/158100) from [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson).<sup>1</sup>

You need to have a question where the tag will be appropriate. If you have found one, or posted one, share a link on meta, and a member with enough rep will create the tag for you, assuming the tag meet [the criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879/158100). It would be helpful if you provide a tag wiki and excerpt as well.

Don't just create a dummy/fake/low quality question for the sake of being able to add the tag. That will cause so much friction that you'll jeopardize your goal.

You might want to elaborate why [podio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/podio) can't be used until qualifying questions for [podio-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/podio-api) exists?

<sup>1. link provided by [sphanley](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324160/can-i-create-a-tag-that-i-know-will-be-used-very-soon#comment350448_324160)</sup>

Comment: I was thinking that questions tagged as `podio` might be product oriented, rather than api oriented, but I'm starting to have second thoughts about it. Pretty much all the questions tagged as `podio` are already API related.

Comment: @domokun If all questions relate to the api you could also request a tag-rename. That needs a mod though and you'll have to be 100% sure there aren't a bunch of questions mis-tagged after the rename.

Comment: I think I'll stick with `podio`, it still makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Then please improve the excerpt and provide a tag wiki @domokun I have an example of a tag wiki and excerpt [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283257/578411)

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty bad... working on it

Comment: Ironically a lot of the questions with [tag:podio] have the DO NOT USE [tag:api] tag as well.

Comment: @Pluto yeah, that tag was obviously [already noticed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255437/burninate-the-api-tag-in-stack-overflow) but no-one started the clean-up so far.

Comment: @Pluto I believe the reason why they're doing it it's because they're asking questions about our API, which is why I wanted [podio-api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/podio-api) in the first place. If they keep doing this we might want to consider changing the `podio` tag in `podio-api`

Comment: @domokun It's worth noting that one can also be a synonym for the other.  Should the need ever arise for another `podio-*` tag, they can be split, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Discussion on Stack Overflow is intended to be initiated by users, rather than products and frameworks themselves.  This doesn't mean you can't encourage developers to ask questions on Stack Overflow, but you probably shouldn't be instantiating that activity.  The inability to create tags without asking questions is a strong indicator that Stack Overflow doesn't work the way you're trying to using it.  **This means you shouldn't try to circumvent these restrictions by creating temporary questions.**

That being said, your question is perfectly reasonable.  It's normal for technology companies to be eager to integrate with developer communities--not just for marketing purposes, but also to keep customers and developers happy.  Unhappy customers aren't customers for very long.  Meta Stack Exchange is meant to be a safe place for you to ask questions about what you can and can't do, and how Stack Overflow is meant to work--which is exactly what you've done.  Hopefully I speak for the majority of the community when I say that we appreciate that thoughtfulness.

It seems like there's some confusion over Stack Overflow's purpose, too.  Remember, Stack Overflow is specifically for **developers and programmers**, not average users.  For product-related questions, your users are more likely to head to the [Project Management community](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/).  Super User tends to be a catch-all for anything that is technical but not quite development- or programming-related.  The Project Management community is more relevant, but newer, still and beta, and not as popular.

Comment: So should or shouldn't  the OP create that tag? Because that message is a bit lost in the explanation about SO, MSO and the other SE sites. I doubt if PM.se is appropriate for what the OP wants to achieve.

Comment: @rene Thanks, updated.  I'm suggesting PM.se as a place for users to ask questions, not a place to go and create a tag.

Comment: do realize that PM.se only accept questions about tools when used in the project management context: http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/393/why-does-our-policy-on-pm-tools-appear-inconsistent

Comment: @rene Right; Podio should still offer their own support, and it's my understanding that they will.  However, for more generic project management questions--for example, questions about scrum--they could encourage customers to visit PM.se.  This would help avoid a scenario where support and SE are playing identical, redundant roles: each has a clearly defined purpose.

Comment: I ended up simply using the `podio` tag, and it's working pretty well as it is. As others pointed out, pm.stackexchange.com would be completely inappropriate, since developers come asking programming questions about our API and SDKs. When people ask questions related to the product instead of programming, we always redirect them on our own support, which is handled through Zendesk and has a completely different focus.